# Is the large Sigma notation (summation notation) used for coproducts?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, notation, direct-sum, direct-product

Binary products in a category are denoted $A_1 \times A_2$, while arbitrary products are denoted $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$. Binary coproducts are (sometimes) denoted $A_1 + A_2$,* so I expected that arbitrary coproducts would (sometimes) be denoted $\sum_{i \in I} A_i$.**

As an explicit example (in $\textbf{Set}$), the binary disjoint union of sets is sometimes denoted by $A_1 + A_2$, and the arbitrary disjoint union of sets by $\sum_{i \in I} A_i$, but I wasn't able to find a reference where $\sum$ is used for coproducts in a general category (I checked Mac Lane's and Awodey's books on category theory, as well as doing a fairly comprehensive Google search).

So my question is: does anybody know of a reference where $\sum$ is used for coproducts? (I would be interested to know if anyone reading this uses this notation personally, even if they do not know of any reference.)

Thanks

---

*although the notations $A_1 \sqcup A_2$ and $A_1 \coprod A_2$ are perhaps more common (and  according to wikipedia $A_1 \oplus A_2$ is also used).

**the notations $\bigsqcup_{i \in I} A_i$ and $\coprod_{i \in I} A_i$ are common (and  according to wikipedia $\bigoplus_{i \in I} A_i$ is also used).

Comment: I'm actually startled to find this isn't a thing that I can find, either. I've been using this as a coproduct notation in my notes for years, but I must have picked it up from type theorists and the usage of $\Sigma$ as a common notation for left adjoints to reindexing functors (which are often coproducts).

Comment: I have definitely seen this notation used in talks, etc. I'm sure I can find a reference for it being used in print, though I agree I'm shocked at how hard a time I'm having.... At the very least, Goldblatt's Topoi uses $a+b$ to denote the coproduct of two elements. So it seems reasonable that he would use $\sum a_i$ to denote an arbitrary coproduct (even though he has no use for it in the book itself)

Comment: Aha! Leinster uses $\sum$ notation in his book [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf). It's introduced on page 127 ^_^

Comment: I think if $\bigoplus_{i \in I}G_i$ were used to represent the coproduct of nonabelian groups (*i.e.* the free product) this would generate a lot of confusion. I think it is only used to represent a coproduct when that coproduct happens to also be a "direct sum", a term which doesn't really have a definition, but, roughly speaking, corresponds to sequences of finite support inside the corresponding product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the interest of providing an answer, I'll restate my comments.

Yes, $\sum A_i$ is used to denote a coproduct by many people (myself included). I've seen this used in plenty of talks, and there was never any confusion.

For an explicit instance of coproducts being introduced this way in print, see the section on "Sums" in Leinster's [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf). In the linked edition, it's page 127.

---

I hope this helps ^_^